# Change iteration direction of for loop

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I want to iterate through some list items in such a way that I would start from a specific position and then go left from it, after that go right from it.

In other words, something like this:

```cs
var items = new List<string>() { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5" };
string item = "Item3";

int index = items.IndexOf(item);

for (int i = index; i >= 0; i--)
    yield return items[i];

for (int i = index + 1; i < items.Count; i++)
    yield return items[i];
```

The result is: `Item3`, `Item2`, `Item1`, `Item4`, `Item5`

Is there a way to achieve this, but using only one for-loop?

Or is there some kind of conditional direction in LINQ?

Comment: Something like `items.Skip(2).Concat(items.Take(2))`?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis that would result in `3,4,5,1,2`, not `3,2,1,4,5`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NZJ2u8

Comment: I'd go with `items.Take(3).Reverse().Concat(items.Skip(3))`

Comment: Why do you want this? Your current solution is working, readable and iterates over your list only once. Any LINQ solution will iterate over your items more than once and solutions without LINQ will harm readability.

Comment: I have to agree with Bill however: your current code is far more readable

Comment: Just read the post, the question is "Is there a way to achieve this, but using only one for-loop?" ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the ternary if and some simple arithmetic on the index to achieve this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    yield return i <= index ? items[index - i] : items[i];
```

Result:

```
Item3
Item2
Item1
Item4
Item5
```

Comment: Omg, so clever and so simple... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use two returns at the same time using one loop, but it is possible to fetch data.

```
for (int i = index; i >= 0; i--)
{
   string answer1 = items[i]; //2,1,0
   if(items.Count - i < items.Count)
      string answer2 = items[items.Count - i]; // 3,4
}
```

Comment: How can this work? It will trigger an out of range exception if `items.Count` is odd or `index != items.Count / 2`

Comment: with condition if(items.Count - i < items.Count)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps, with tuple deconstruction:

```cs
var items = new List<string>() { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5" };
string item = "Item3";

int index = items.IndexOf(item);

for ((int i, int j) = (index, 0); j < items.Count; i--, j++){
    if(i>=0){
       yield return items[i];
    } else {
       yield return item[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using the *pythonic* way would be by generating the sequence of indexes using `Enumerable.Range`.

```
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, index + 1).Reverse().Union(Enumerable.Range(index + 1, items.Count - index - 1)))
    yield return items[i];
```

But in terms of performance and maintainability, I would go with your existing solution using *two separate for-loops*.

In terms of making the intent of your code more clearly, I would go with `items.Take(3).Reverse().Concat(items.Skip(3))` as it says directly what will happen.

Comment: You should just return you LINQ result in this case, the foreach deserves nothing but doing (yet) antoher iteration. But thanks to merge python logic and C# coding :)